# Angular 2 - Best approach for a loading / busy modal

Tags: angular, typescript

Hopefully a quick question, what would be a maintainable approach for calling a loading / busy modal throughout your application? Of course the nature of it would be required to be used on several screens throughout the app. Would it be best to have a component which has an ngstyle on it to show it? And would you have to put the logic of it to show on every single http request or could you simplify it show how by using it once in your httpservice?

Comment: you should be using progress bars or spinners available every where

Comment: Personally, I use Pace, which seems perfect for what you need. http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When implementing something like this, I recommend creating a component + service combination. Your component is the visual aspect - style it however you wish. But the key part is that your service exposes a simple boolean/Observable that your component binds its visibility to (through a simple ngIf).

That means that if you ensure you provide your loading service at the root injector level, you can inject that service into any other component/service that needs to show the loading indicator and by toggling the boolean on your service, you toggle whether the loading indicator shows or hides.

A simple and clean implementation.

So, my service might look like:

```
export class LoadingIndicator {
  private _isLoading = false;

  isLoading(): boolean {
    return this._isLoading;
  }

  show(): void {
    this._isLoading = true;
  }

  hide(): void {
    this._isLoading = false;
  }
}
```

You bind your LoadingIndicatorComponent to that isLoading() method. (You could use the property directly as well - i tend to be over cautious to encapsulate things from my Java days, but for such a simple use case, it is not strictly necessary).

And to ensure this injects into the root constructor, i provide this service in my AppModule - ensuring there will be only one instance of my service.

Comment: So the variable on the ngif is a global variable which you either set to true or false? Also how would I make it available at the root injector level?

Comment: updated the answer to add more context, but essentially, yes the variable binding to ngIf more or less acts like a global variable, and i provide the service to the AppModule to ensure it's injected only once at the root injector level

Comment: This is great thanks :)